# Jquery that will add a class to a div if the height is exactly 18px only

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class to a div if the height is exactly 18px. But I need the jquery to add it to only divs that have a height of 18px, anything longer than that don't add a class. here's my jquery, right now it adds a class to every div instead of the ones that are only 18px, so I added the removeClass but now it just doesn't work. If it's easier to add a class to a div only if the height is bigger than 18px I can use that too.

```
if ($(".CategoryDescription").height() == 18) {
    $('.CategoryDescription').addClass('VerticalAlign');
}

else {
    $('.CategoryDescription').removeClass('VerticalAlign');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to iterate over all the elements, and check **each one** for it's height, and set the class accordingly

```
$(".CategoryDescription").each(function() {
    if ( $(this).height() == 18 ) {
        $(this).addClass('VerticalAlign');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('VerticalAlign');
    }
});
```

You could use `toggleClass` with a state argument as well

```
$(".CategoryDescription").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('VerticalAlign', $(this).height() == 18);
});
```